# Fitting a equation to a spiral curve

Tags: regression, curves, noneuclidean-geometry

I am completely new to this forum and also to this type of mathematical modeling.
I am interested to fit the following equation to the points obtained from experimental data. I am looking for an algorithm or in the best case a matlab program that does it.

Equation: 
r(θ)=A/[log(B tan(θ/2N))] to the following curve (image)
[image: spiral curve with a straight line at the beginning]

The equation is obtained from this article.
http://arxiv.org/abs/0908.0892

Thank you very much in advance

Ashwin

Comment: Have you tried anything? Matlab's [`nlinfit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nlinfit.html) maybe?

Comment: What are your data ? $(x,y)$ or anything else ?

Comment: Hi Horchler, I am not able to use nlinfit as I do not have the tool box.

Comment: I have experimental data in x,y. The formula is in r, theta. I have the values of r for different theta and I have converted them into x, y values.

Comment: @ Ashwin :  Do you want to compute $A$ and $B$ with a known value $N$ ? Or do you want to compute $A$, $B$ and $N$ ?